# onload function(this) from onclick in another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where there is a button. The button has an onclick function, where it calls the function pop to produce an alert. The alert shows the attribute of the button's data-message.

I am trying to redirect this function to onload to another page, hence the href.

What I would like to produce is for the alert to be displayed on the 2nd page as well when the body onloads.

I have tried to change and swap my codes between the 2 different HTML, however I often get the error of Uncaught TypeError: e.getAttribute is not a function.

Here are the relevant codes for page 1 where the button needs to be clicked:

```
<a href="dump2.html"><button type="button" data-message="button1" onclick="pop(this)">click</button></a>
```

```
<script>
function pop(e) {
    alert(e.getAttribute("data-message"));
}
</script>
```

---

Page 2 where I will onload the attribute I have gotten from the button clicked on Page 1

```
<body onload="pop(this)"> </body>
<script>
  function pop(e) {
      alert(e.getAttribute("data-message"));
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Variables don't persist between pages. `this` in the `onload` refers to page 2 body, not the button they clicked on in page 2.

Comment: you can use cookies, localStorage, sessionStorage, or URL query parameters to pass data from page 1 to page 2.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much for your help! I've figured it out :)